# Ldap configuration in Spring Security - own class

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

I want to write my own LDAP authentication provider. I am extending `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`, which has a method `retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)`.

I want to override this method and write my own data retrieving method. How to do that in Java? How to make an LDAP query and how connect to the LDAP server? I was searching in Internet but I didn't find anything that helped.

EDIT: 22.01.2013

```
@Override
protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    LdapUser userDetail = null;

    log.entry("retrieveUser", authentication.getPrincipal());

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = authentication;
    String userName = userToken.getName();
    userName = userName != null ? userName.toLowerCase() : userName;
    String password = userToken.getCredentials().toString();

    try {
        if (password == null || "".equals(password)) {
            log.debug("retrieveUser", "no password provided");
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(
                    "Invalid login or password");
        }
    }

    catch (AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException e) {
        log.debug("retrieveUser", "no password provided");
    }

    // connection with ldap and check retrieved username and password
    connect = connection(userName, password);

    if (connect) {
        log.debug("retrieve user", "correct connection with ldap");
        userDetail = new LdapUser();
        setUserDetails(userDetail, ctx, username);

    } else {
        log.error("retrieve user", "Failed connection");
    }

    log.exit("retrieveUser", "user logged: " + userDetail);
    return userDetail;
}
```

My security.xml file

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.ico" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.gif" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.jpg" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.png" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp"/>


    <form-login login-page="/index.jsp"
    authentication-failure-url="/error_ldap.jsp" 
    default-target-url="/main_ldap.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />                 
    </http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthenticationProvider">  
        <password-encoder hash="sha" /> 
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When login is suceed I got redirect to main_ldap.jsp, but if authentication fail, I got this error. I tried to throw exception UsernameNotFoundException instead returning null in retrieveUser method (which is not allowed) but anything happend (only i got this exception).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to LDAP from java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html

but spring security already has ldap integration, you can use of the methods described here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html

...

xml config for using your own UserDetails service is:

```
<b:bean id="userDetailsService" class="your.class.here">
</b:bean>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
</authentication-provider>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have to use custom provider which will be extended retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) cause I have to do this to my work. I suppose I have to use somehow UserServiceImpl class but don't any idea about implementation.

Comment: Any idea how to get data in retrieveUser method and add them to UserDetail object?

Comment: Ok, finally I connected to ldap on localhost, and I can retrieve information about specific user which is settled on ldap server. But now, how to put information about this user into UserDetail object?

Comment: There is a service UserDetailsService with method  UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username), when you implement this service you can return a new UserDetailsImpl. I'll edit the answer with the xml config.

Comment: Ok thanks @Asymmetric33 but how to implement correctly this service when I want retrieve data from ldap server?

Comment: You make your own class that implements that interface, in that class you will have a method that returns a UserDetails object for a username the user tries to login with, in that method you connect to LDAP and get info for that user, put it in a new UserDetailsImpl object and return it. Don't forget to add the xml config to your appcontext.

Comment: Ok, after many problems finally I can connect with ldap and logging operation is working correct. But when somebody is not on my ldap server application should redirect me to my error page. But instead that, when authentication is failed I'm getting exception: retrieveUser returned null - a violation of the interface contract. Yes, if there is no user on server I returned null, but I think that is good. I edited firs post and added my retrieveUser method. Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok, finally I solved this problem. I changed my conception and use my class which implement UserDetailService. I have in this class loadByUsername method. I will override this method. Inside it I made LdapUser object which implements UserDetails interface. I got this object through LdapUserDetailService. This is class which connect to my ldap server, retrieve user from this server and make LdapUser object. I have a little problem witch hash password, but I think that I can handle with that. Hope, it will be helpful for somebody.

Comment: Today I found error in my previous solution. I throw exception UsernameNotFoundException from acegisecurity, not from springframework security and because of import I didn't see this... 3 days of thinking, analizing... Finally I solved this and now it works ;)